# Define blueprints grouping objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Django modelling question:

I'm writing a manufacturing e-commerce site. We have an inventory of all components and we want to define blueprints for products that we could build using those components. How could I model that?

Say for example I have a class *AtomicComponent*

```py
class AtomicComponent(models.Model):

    component = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    thickness = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    colour = component = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

+----+------------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+
| id | Component  | length | thickness | colour | quantity |
+----+------------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+
| 45 | table-legs |     80 | 3         | white  |       90 |
| 46 | table-tops |    100 | 3         | white  |       25 |
| 47 | bolts      |      1 | null      | null   |     3000 |
+----+------------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

How could I specify blueprints like:

ikea-table: 4x(id=45) + 1x(id=46) + 4x(id=47)

Trying to find a way so that the product could have a relationship with specific objects so that when a customer tries to order a table, it would check if all the components are available.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another model to store each component of the blueprint:

```
class Blueprint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    atomic_component = models.ForeignField(AtomicComponent, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='components')
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

This model with store a record for every component in the blueprint, with the amount of them on field ´amount´.